# Not able to get the accept-language header on a Phoenix LiveView

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a liveview route where I need to get the `accept-language` header.

I've tried to call [connect_info/2](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#get_connect_info/2) on `mount/3` but it looks like not all headers are available there.

I've also tried to create a `Plug` and add the `language` to the `session`. However, I only need it for one specific route. So, I'd rather do it on `mount/3` instead. Is there a way to get the `accept-language` header there?

Comment: this might be the only viable solution at the moment, don't forget that liveview is still unstable, so it might get fixed in later releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `connect_info` you can get just a subset of information passed as request headers (`:peer_data, :trace_context_headers, :x_headers, :uri`) assuming you have modified your web socket in `endpoint.ex` like so:

```
socket "/live", Phoenix.LiveView.Socket, websocket: [connect_info: [:user_agent, :x_headers, :uri, :peer_data, :trace_context_headers, session: @session_options]]
```

to get the other headers like `accept-language` you would need to pass it over from conn object to your live views somehow. You can simply do it with session. Create a simple plug to do that or add that to your existing plug (eg. authentication)

```
conn
|> put_session(:accepted_lang, get_req_header(conn, "accept-language"))
|> assign(:current_user, user)
```

and in your LiveView's `mount` just read it

```
   def mount(_params, session, socket) do
     
     lang = session["accepted_lang"]
     .....
   end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did but I was trying to figure out if there was a way to get the `accept-language` header from the `socket` like we do with `get_req_header(conn, "accept-language")`. It looks like there isn't a way to do it.